# Salesforce Visual force pages

Tags: html, xhtml, salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-ios-sdk

My object is `Consumer`:

Here is a `Consumer` object has a following fields and want to create a record. But the null pointer exception is reported.

**Visualforce page:**

```
<apex:page controller="signup1" >
<apex:form >
<h1>User SignUp</h1>
<apex:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-top:2em;">
<p><b>Name :</b><br />
<apex:inputField id="name" value="{!con.Name}"/>
</p>
<p><b>Address :</b><br />
<apex:inputField id="address" value="{!con.address__c}"/>
</p>
<p><b>Email Id :</b><br />
<apex:inputField required="true" id="emailid" value="{!con.email_id__c}"/>
</p>
<p><b>Password :</b><br />
<apex:inputSecret id="password" value="{!con.password__c}"/>
</p>
<p><b>Confirm Password :</b><br />
<apex:inputSecret id="confirmpassword" value="{!con.Confirm_Password__c}"/>
</p>
<p><b>Security Question :</b><br />
<apex:inputField required="true" id="securityquestion" value="{!con.Security_Question__c}"/>
</p>
<p><b>Answer :</b><br />
<apex:inputField required="true" id="answer" value="{!con.Answer__c}" />
</p>
<p><b>Ph No :</b><br />
<apex:inputField required="true" id="phno" value="{!con.phone__c}"/>
</p>
<p><b>Pan Card No :</b><br />
<apex:inputField required="true" id="pancardno" value="{!con.Pan_Card_No__c}"/>
</p>
<p> <apex:commandButton action="{!registerUser}" value="SignUp" id="SignUp"/></p>
</apex:panelGrid>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>

controller :
public class signup1
{

    Consumer__c con = new Consumer__c();

    public void signup1()
    {
        con = [SELECT Name, address__c, email_id__c, password__c, Confirm_Password__c, Security_Question__c, Answer__c, phone__c from Consumer__c where  Name =: ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Name')];
    }

    public Consumer__c getcon()
    {
    return con;
    }

  public PageReference registerUser() 
  {
      try
      {
          insert Con;
      }
      catch(System.DMLException e)
      {
         ApexPages.addMessages(e);
         return null;
      }

      PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl());
      pageRef.setRedirect(true);
      return pageRef;
  } 
}
```

I cannot insert data into the `Consumer` object due to the null exception.

Answer (score 0):

This coding the entirely wrong.
1. What is the purpose of the fetching the fields Name, address__c, email_id__c, password__c, Confirm_Password__c, Security_Question__c, Answer__c and phone__c from customer object, as those input fields only.
2. why don't you have Standard Controller on Customer object.
3. If you are fetching values based on name, you need to put search button next to name field and fetch values.

regards,
PK

Answer (score 0):

Consumer is not accessible in your Visual Force page as there is no getter or setter method for it.

```
public class signup1
{
   public Consumer__c con {get; set;}

   public signup1()
   {
     try
     {
       // Make sure 'ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Name')' is indeed not null.
       con = [SELECT Name, address__c, email_id__c, password__c, Confirm_Password__c, Security_Question__c, Answer__c, phone__c from Consumer__c where  Name =: ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Name')];
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
        system.debug(ex.getMessage());
     }
   }
    ..............
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the values retrieved from the VF page into any parameter in the controller. First set them. Then create a object of type Consumer and then assign these values from VF page into the fields from the object. Only then you will be able to insert con.